# Inicializar SharedPreferences desde una clase que no extiende de activity

Tags: java, android

Estoy intentando que una app se autoinicie al encender el dispositivo siempre y cuando así lo quiera el usuario. Para ello, guardo el valor de una variable mediante `SharedPreference`. El problema es que para ello uso unos métodos de Leer y Guardar, que al estar en `MainActivity`, deben estar en el `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity //implements View.OnClickListener
{
 static SharedPreferences datos;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
(...)
 datos= getPreferences(this.MODE_PRIVATE);
(...)
    } 

public static void Guardar(String guardado, String fichero)
        {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=datos.edit();
            editor.putString(fichero, guardado);
            editor.commit();
        }

        public static String Leer(String fichero)
        {
            String e=datos.getString(fichero, "" );
            return e;
        }
```

La clase en la que uso es método de leer para saber si el usuario ha elegido o no la opción de autoarranque es la siguiente:

```
 public class Monitor extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        String auto= MainActivity.Read("auto");
       if(auto.equals("true"))
       {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
       }
    }
}
```

El problema es que trata de ejecutar el método leer desde `Monitor` al empezar su ejecución, pero al intentar hacer esto, la app se para debido a que datos está sin inicializar, puesto que no se inicializa en el propio método, sino en el `onCreate` del `MainActivity`, que aún no se ha ejecutado. No obstante, no puedo meterlo en el método debido a que este debe ser static para poder usarlo en otras clases, por lo que no puedo pasarle el context al método. Por otra parte, intenté crear los métodos `Guardar()` y `Leer()` en la clase Monitor, pero tampoco puedo, ya que me da error al intentar usar `getPreferences()`.

¿Qué puedo hacer? ¿Hay alguna manera de usar `SharedPreferences` en este caso? Y, en caso de que no la haya, ¿Cómo podría almacenar la decisión del usuario de una ejecución a otra?

Comment: Que realiza el método Read()? Me imagino que en realidad te refieres a Leer ()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**En un Broadcasteceiver el método onReceive(), recibe el contexto el cual puedes utilizar para obtener tu prefefencia:**

```
onReceive (Context context, Intent intent)
```

---

Define dentro de tus métodos, el nombre de la preferencia e instancia SharedPreferences dentro de cada método:

```
private String PREFS_KEY = "mispreferencias";

public static void guardarValor(Context context, String keyPref, String valor) {
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString(keyPref, mostrar);
    editor.commit();
}



public static String obtenerValor(Context context, String keyPref) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    return  preferences.getString(keyPref, "");
}
```

Sugiero uses el contexto para llamar los métodos, por ejemplo Leer () dentro de tu BroadcastReceiver:

```
obtenerValor(context, "auto");
```