# ¿Cómo mantengo la sesión activa al cerrar mi aplicación?

Tags: android, android-studio, login

AL salir de la aplicación se cierra sesión automaticamente y tengo que volver a colocar usuario y contraseña, estaba leyendo sobre usar :

`getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);`

> ¿Cuál sería la manera correcta de mantener la sesión activa incluso al
>   reiniciar el celular?

Comment: Si es para poca cantidad de información, puede utilizar el `SharedPreference` para la peristencia de datos. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: Eso estaba leyendo, ¿es el mejor metedo a implementar en este caso? gracias por su respuesta

Comment: Esta respuesta de @jorgesys te puede ayudar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/90368/22603

Comment: Muchas Gracias.

Comment: @PedroLizarraga agrega la forma en que guardas la sesión, como te autenticas?

Comment: @acklay yo creo que no importa la cantidad en este caso, si son datos sensibles, o extremadamente importantes que no deben ser de dominio publico, no es recomendable usar las opciones de almacenamiento como archivos, preferencias, bases de datos en el dispositivo y si se usan usar algún método de encriptación.

Comment: Es para no volver a introducir el usuario y la contraseña y asi cada que se apague el cel o que se reinicie o salga de la aplicacion, no tengas que volver a introducirlos

Comment: @Jorgesys Usted tiene toda razón. No se recomienda guardar contraseñas en el uso de SharedPreference. Lo ideal sería crear token con expiración de vez en cuando.

Comment: entonces es preferible crear un token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes que nada esta linea, no es usada para "mantener una sesión", en realidad se usa para mantener la pantalla del dispositivo siempre encendida, y no cumple el objetivo que deseas.

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

---

En realidad el guardar credenciales en tu dispositivo se realiza generalmente cuando la información que intentas guardar no es sensible, de otra forma  tal vez sería conveniente un WebService.

Si tu información no es sensible puedes usar `SharedPreferences`, estos son los métodos:

```
private String PREFS_KEY = "mispreferencias";

public static void guardarValor(Context context, String keyPref, String valor) {
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString(keyPref, mostrar);
    editor.commit();
}        

public static String leerValor(Context context, String keyPref) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    return  preferences.getString(keyPref, "");
}
```

Con los métodos anteriores puedes guardar tus credenciales, por ejemplo:

```
guardarValor("user",<nombre usuario>);
guardarValor("password",<clave de acceso>);
```

para recuperarlos, puedes realizarlo en el método `onCreate()` y usar los métodos:

```
String usuario = leerValor("user");
String password = leerValor("password");
```

no es recomendable usar las opciones de almacenamiento como archivos, preferencias, bases de datos en el dispositivo y si se usan usar algún método de encriptación.

Comment: de hecho es nada mas para el usuario y la contraseña, para no tener que introducirlos cada que se salga de la aplicacion o que se apague el telefono

Comment: Hola, disculpen pero tengo un problema similar, use Shared Preferences pero  no me esta dando resultados, yo tengo un spinner que selecciona un IP y con un switch hace la conexión del hilo al servidor, estoy almacenando esos datos en el Shared pero el Spinner no se queda grabado y el switch si pero igual, solo se quedan ahi los datos pero la sesion sigue cerrada. Ayuda por favor! urgente :(

Comment: @Bloom realiza una pregunta e indicanos cual es, te ayudamos con gusto !

Comment: sorry por haber escrito por aca, pero es que no puedo hacer preguntas :( , por eso acudo de esta manera. ayuda por favor

Comment: @Bloom acabo de ver que estas bloqueado, te sugiero en verdad realices preguntas en base a [ask] y respuestas en base a [answer], y no responder en inglés ya que el idioma oficial es español, esperemos puedas pronto realizar preguntas :-(